# Does display:none still use performance of rendering

Tags: css, browser, resources, rendering, responsive-design

Lets say i have markup such as this

```
<div style='display:none'>
    <!--Flash Object-->
</div>
```

Would the browser still use resources to load the Flash object, Or would it be delayed till a javascript call is made to switch the `dislplay:block`;

Now please bear in mind I am not talking about loading the object. I am talking about rendering it. The reason why i clarify this is because if I change the flash object to an `img` tag it would still download the resource.

The main reason behind this is `responsive css design` its all well and good changing your website to a css layout to suit the screen but rendering resources takes time and im not sure how browsers handle resources that are downloaded just not rendered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes , sure, whatever status the "display" attribute is, the flash resource(including regular image, or a music, or something else) will be always rendered.

For my experience, the "display" attribute has no business with "eager/delay loading". If you want to render an object at the last moment, I suggest you use javascript or some other approach.

Comment: I suppose this is where responsive design is not so responsive. To load and unload resources is going to be annoying say if the user switches the orientation on his phone.