# Performance improvements with display:none

Tags: javascript, css

I'm working on a project where large pannable images are viewed on tablet devices.  To get around Mobile Safari's memory limitations for large images I am tiling segments of an image to create one large image.

The user can scale and rotate as well as pan around this image, these transformations can be quite slow due to the number of images (we're talking 36 500x500px images).

Before going to the trouble of implementing it, I was wondering setting the display property of offscreen tiles to 'none' would provide a significant performance improvement in the speed of the transformations at this scale?

Comment: Anything the browser doesn't have to actually *draw* will offer an improvement, but the download(s) will still happen, obviously. This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9078960/does-displaynone-still-use-performance-of-rendering?rq=1

Comment: So say I had 5 of the 36 tiles displayed, would a transformation to their container be rendered faster than if all 36 tiles were displayed?  Say the container has undergone a transformation and then a tile has its display property changed and is rendered, is the transformation applied to it at this stage (i.e it wasn't applied before thus saving some time in rendering the transformation of the container) or have the calculations for its position already been made? (implying the transformation call still did the same amount of computation)

Comment: Yes. The position *will* be computed at first draw, but it won't have to be rendered (drawn) frame by frame as the user scales and pans the 'image'. It's *that* action that saves the performance. Stitching images together is always problematic, but your idea, IMHO, will mitigate the nerf effects.