# Html table hide columns best practice

Tags: html

I have an html table and I want to be able to hide and show columns dynamically (based on certain values on page load). It could be a large number of columns I need to hide.

I was considering taking the values from the columns that I want to be hidden and putting their values in a `data-` attribute on the `<tr>` element to and avoid creating dom elements that aren't being shown in the ui. I need the values somewhere because they are used in click events.

Are there any best practices out there that say it is bad to load columns into a table and hide them with say `display: none;`, or am I just over thinking it and being anal and should just hide them with css?

Comment: How many rows and columns are likely to be in this table? If it's a small amount, then it won't really matter how you do it - pick the easiest way. If it's going to have the potential to be massive, that's when you should start to care...

Comment: It can be massive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm unsure of any types of practices particularly for this application. Also based on the information given so far.

The way you are doing it is **not** the best choice of going about this situation. You are taking data and putting them all in their own elements which not only clusters up HTML with unessessary elements (that are always hidden by CSS) but also can be more taxing then it has to on you and your viewers computer.

When you could be using  the `data attribute` this is a great way to keep the information more consolated, less clutter, well organized, easy to read and manage. Also even when a element has the styling `display:none` it is still using the computer performance to render all of those elements.

You can read this thread that explains: [Read More](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9079213/4573329)

Comment: I need to hide the column from the table but still have access to the data. In my head, it seems like it is better to not have the elements in the dom at all and just to load the data, no?

Comment: @blubberbo So if I got this right you are loading the data from the Html? You are wondering if hiding the elements will cause it not to be able to get the information

Comment: No the data is being loaded via the backend and I have links in the data table rows that rely on the data in the hidden columns. Before I would just "display: false;" the columns and then still be able to target them with js. But now it seems like an opportunity to use "data-" and not have to have the columns in the dom at all, but I wanted some external confirmation that that is the right thing to do

Comment: @blubberbo Ohhh. I see what you are saying now. So you took the data hide them so you can utilize with JS. Correct? Yes way better idea using  data attribute. Much simpler and cleaner way of doing it.

Comment: yup, that's it. Is there anywhere you might know of that I could show coworkers about best practices saying that?

Comment: @blubberbo well if you don't need to show the information in the table and you need to just ripe the information off html using the attribute is the best way of going about it. It truly is a no brainer. That's why I was confused about your question cause I didn't understand why you needed a element in the first place if your just going to hide it.

Comment: @blubberbo I'll try researching it up see if I can find you some proof. But just thinking what it's doing I already know it's not a good way of doing it